# Is it possible to return values from an infinite loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, sockets, infinite

I'm writing a program that takes GPU temps and system ID from different systems on a local network and sends it to one main system. I'm having an issue with the receiving part of my program. In my function that accepts the data, I have an infinite loop to continue constantly receiving data from the client system. I also need to take this data out of this function and display it on a tkinter ui. I'm stuck on how to keep the data updating, while also returning it into my GUI

```
import tkinter as tk
import socket

def startServer():
    HOST = socket.gethostname()
    PORT = 9999
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.bind((HOST, PORT))
        s.listen()
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        with conn:
            print(f"NEW CONNECTION: {addr}")
            while True:
                data = conn.recv(1024)
                if not data:
                    break
                conn.sendall(data)
                data.decode('utf-8')
                data = str(data)
                data = data.split(':')
                return data[0], data[1]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    running = True
    window = tk.Tk()
    window.geometry('600x600')
    button = tk.Button(window, text='Connect', command=startServer)
    button.pack()
    label = tk.Label(window,text='')

    window.mainloop()
    running = False
```

Comment: That code is not going to work.  Your `startServer` never returns to the main loop, so the UI will be frozen.  You should just start a thread to run the server.  You can have it store the data in globals, then use `window.after` to run something every second (or whatever) to update the UI from the globals.

Comment: @TimRoberts Alright thanks for the comment, I added two global vars `ID = ''
TEMP = '' `. I'm running into an issue with the thread (I haven't used the library much at all) I added this `threading.Thread(target=startServer(), daemon=True).start()` to my code, although after when I run this the program hangs when it reaches this line. Not entirely sure what I am doing wrong here any help appreciated.

Comment: `target=startServer()` --- that immediately CALLS the function, and passes its return value as the target.  What you need is `target=startServer`.  Pass the function object, don't call the function.

Comment: @juinbo What is your updated code right now?